# Array with arrays, memory issue

Tags: objective-c

How could I create the following array without having memory leaks:

It should be an array with arrays inside

```
 arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], 
                [[NSMutableArray alloc] init],    
                [[NSMutableArray alloc] init],
                [[NSMutableArray alloc] init],     
                [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], 
                [[NSMutableArray alloc] init],     
                [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], nil];
```

Comment: `+(id)arrayWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems` ?

Comment: Use `[NSMutableArray array]` rather than your alloc/init approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[NSMutableArray array]` instead, which creates an autoreleased object that you don't have to worry about:

```
arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
            [NSMutableArray array], 
            [NSMutableArray array],    
            [NSMutableArray array],
            [NSMutableArray array],     
            [NSMutableArray array], 
            [NSMutableArray array],     
            [NSMutableArray array], nil];
```

Note that you must retain / release `arr` if you want to hold onto it.
If what you really want is simply arrays of arrays, I have a class called `RJGrid` which will do this for you, and is faster than multiple `NSMutableArrays` (linked lists are slow for lookups).

You can download the class [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25258177/personal/RJGrid.zip), in my dropbox. It uses ARC, but is simple enough to convert to a reference counted environment, if you want me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using ARC, you don’t need to do anything. If you aren’t using ARC, then you can autorelease the arrays:

```
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease], 
                [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease],    
                [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease],
                [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease],     
                [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease], 
                [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease],     
                [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease], nil];
```

Comment: `[NSMutableArray array]` is about half as many keystrokes, and easier to read/understand.

Comment: Is there some way to use an NSAutorelasePool to simplify it? (No idea... I'm a Objective-C newb with about 10 days of experience).

Comment: @JasonDown no, you'd need to have ARC enabled. I honestly would recommend you learn manual reference counting first, however.

Comment: ARC is where the reference counting is handled for you right? (Gives you compile errors if you try to use [release xxx] and things like [super dealloc])

Answer (score 1):

Use an autorelease memory pool and release the pool when you are done with your arr variable.

http://www.alphero.com/mobile-development/understanding-objective-c-autorelease-memory-management/